# Typescript & Redux connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to connect redux to a component using Typescript and keep running into the same error.

> Argument of type 'typeof BaseLayoutUnconnected' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Component < any, {}, any>'.   Property 'setState' is
>   missing in type 'typeof BaseLayoutUnconnected'.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IBaseLayoutProps, IBaseLayoutState } from './base-layout.types';
import { ChatContainer } from '../../components';
import { connect, DispatchProp } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { ChatActions } from 'app/actions';
import { RootState } from 'app/reducers';
import { omit } from 'app/utils';

export const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, ownProps) => {
    return {
        chatItems: state.chatItems
    };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(omit(ChatActions, 'Type'), dispatch)
});

export class BaseLayoutUnconnected extends React.Component<IBaseLayoutProps, IBaseLayoutState> {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        const { actions, chatItems } = this.props;
        return <ChatContainer actions={actions} chatItems={chatItems} />;
    }
}

export const BaseLayout = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(BaseLayoutUnconnected);
```

This is being called in my app.tsx via

```
 <Route exact={true} path="/" component={BaseLayout} />
```

Here are the props and state

```
export interface IBaseLayoutProps {
    chatItems: RootState.ChatState;
    actions: ChatActions;
}

export interface IBaseLayoutState {}
```

ChatActions looks like

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
import { ChatItemModel } from 'app/models';

export namespace ChatActions {
    export enum Type {
        ADD_CHAT_ITEM = 'ADD_CHAT_ITEM'
    }

    export const addChatItem = createAction<PartialPick<ChatItemModel, 'text'>>(Type.ADD_CHAT_ITEM);
}

export type ChatActions = Omit<typeof ChatActions, 'Type'>;
```

Comment: try to add default values for `this.state`

Comment: Adding constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
 } doesn't fix the issue.  Edited the original question to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a problem i had too when i first started with Redux and TypeScript. There is a tricky solution. The connect methode takes alot of generics. I try to explain it with your example.

First of all you have to split the properties of your BaseLayoutUnconnected.

```
export interface IBaseLayoutStateProps {
    chatItems: RootState.ChatState;
}

export interface IBaseLayoutDispatchProps {
    actions: ChatActions;
}

export interface IBaseLayoutOwnProps {
    // put properties here you want to make available from the connected component
}

export type IBaseLayoutProps = IBaseLayoutOwnProps & IBaseLayoutDispatchProps & IBaseLayoutStateProps 

export interface IBaseLayoutState {}
```

Then you have to fill the generics of the different redux functions.

```
const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<IBaseLayoutStateProps, {}, RootState> = (state: RootState): IBaseLayoutStateProps => ({
    chatItems: state.chatItems
})

export const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsFunction<IBaseLayoutDispatchProps, IBaseLayoutOwnProps> = (dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: IBaseLayoutDispatchProps): IBaseLayoutDispatchProps => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(omit(ChatActions, 'Type'), dispatch)
});

export default connect<IBaseLayoutStateProps , IBaseLayoutDispatchProps, IBaseLayoutOwnProps , RootState>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(BaseLayoutUnconnected as any)
```

a good source, where you can find all this stuff i wrote and more is [this repository](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide)

Comment: Thanks @Sly321.  Changed everything as you suggested, but getting similar error.  It now says "Argument of type 'typeof BaseLayoutUnconnected' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component < IBaseLayoutOwnProps, {}, any>'. Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof BaseLayoutUnconnected'."

Comment: Where do you get the error? In the Router or in the Connect function? Do you have a repository where i can checkout the source?

Comment: the error is occuring in the connect function.  BaseLayoutUnconnected (in the connect function) is underlined.

Comment: Since there is nothing missing in your code in my opinion, do you have all the requirements in your package.json? I'll post some package versions that work for me.
    "react":"16.4.2"
    "react-dom":"16.4.2"
    "react-redux":"5.0.7"
    "redux":"4.0.0"
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.7"
    "@types/react-redux": "6.0.6"
    "@types/react-router-dom":"4.3.0"
I don't have @types/react in this configuration, BUT i would definitly try out to add @types/react if there is a chance.
A good idea is the command: yarn why @types/react
try to find out if there a sideeffects from other packages

Comment: Another idea, try to call BaseLayoutUnconnect in the connect like this
connect<generics & stuff>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseLayoutUnconnect as any as React.Component).

If this still errors, then is something wrong with your @types configuration

Comment: BaseLayoutUnconnect as any worked!  Going to add that to your answer and accept it.